# How Do I Make My Specific Title Show Up Only On Mobile Screens?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This is what I have so far, but I can't get it to work.

HTML

```
<h3 class="screentest">Hello world</h3>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width:750px){
.screentest {display: none;}
}
@media (min-width:750px){
.screentest {display: none;}
}
```

Comment: `.screentest {display: block;}` should be applied outside of a media query, seeing as it's the "default" property-value you're applying to the element.

Answer (score 2):

You have in two  `@media`  `display:none;`. Change that `display` inside  `@media (max-width:750px)` to  `display:block`.